# Missing values in ejb-jar.xml

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, ejb-jar.xml

When trying to deploy a mavenized entreprise application (including both war and jar projects) in glassfish 4.0, (using netbeans 7.3.1),i got the similar problem as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085064/exception-deploying-ejb-jar-to-glassfish) saying that the jar is invalid as it contains zero ejb (which is not true because my application jar contains 4 entity classes with their correspondent session beans and local interfaces). As the solution in that post was to add the ejb-jar.xml then i did the same by adding my deployement descriptor written as the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <ejb-jar xmlns = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         version = "3.1"
         xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd">


    <enterprise-beans>

        <session>
            <ejb-name>EnginDao</ejb-name>
            <ejb-class>com.crystaleez.dao.EnginDao</ejb-class>
            <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
            <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
        </session>

        <session>
            <ejb-name>AdresseDao</ejb-name>
            <ejb-class>com.crystaleez.dao.AdresseDao</ejb-class>
            <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
            <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
        </session>

        <session>
            <ejb-name>AutomobilisteDao</ejb-name>
            <ejb-class>com.crystaleez.dao.AutomobilisteDao</ejb-class>
            <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
            <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
        </session>

        <session>
            <ejb-name>GaragisteDao</ejb-name>
            <ejb-class>com.crystaleez.dao.GaragisteDao</ejb-class>
            <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
            <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
        </session>


    </enterprise-beans>


</ejb-jar>
```

So i got the following exception saying that this exception occuring when deploying the application, the ejb-jar.xml has an invalid content and that one of the values '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":interceptors, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":relationships, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":assembly-descriptor, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":ejb-client-jar}' is expected (for me it's in french, i coudn't find a way to change the glassfish logging in netbeans)

> Grave:   Exception lors du déploiement de l'application
>   [tunmecanique-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT] : org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
>   lineNumber: 16; columnNumber: 24; Fichier de descripteur de
>   déploiement META-INF/ejb-jar.xml dans l'archive
>   [tunmecanique-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT_jar].  cvc-complex-type.2.4.a : Contenu
>   non valide trouvé à partir de l'élément 'enterprise-beans'. L'une des
>   valeurs '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":interceptors,
>   "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":relationships,
>   "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":assembly-descriptor,
>   "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":ejb-client-jar}' est attendue.
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 16; columnNumber: 24;
>   Fichier de descripteur de déploiement META-INF/ejb-jar.xml dans
>   l'archive [tunmecanique-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT_jar].  cvc-complex-type.2.4.a
>   : Contenu non valide trouvé à partir de l'élément 'enterprise-beans'.
>   L'une des valeurs '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":interceptors,
>   "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":relationships,
>   "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":assembly-descriptor,
>   "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":ejb-client-jar}' est attendue.    at
>   com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:324)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:245)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readStandardDeploymentDescriptor(Archivist.java:665)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:391)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:271)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:280)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationArchivist.readModulesDescriptors(ApplicationArchivist.java:611)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationArchivist.openWith(ApplicationArchivist.java:229)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openWith(ApplicationFactory.java:232)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.processDOL(DolProvider.java:188)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:222)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:96)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:878)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:818)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:374)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)    at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)

I don't have any of these values on my project(actually i don't know what is an interceptor neither other required values said by the exception) (i don't know why ejb-jar.xml is mandatory and why there is no way to generate it automatically) i just need to make my project being deployed sucessfully.

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that you have a different order for `session-type` and `transaction-type` in the last two declarations. Try the following:

```
    <session>
        <ejb-name>AutomobilisteDao</ejb-name>
        <ejb-class>com.crystaleez.dao.AutomobilisteDao</ejb-class>
        <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
        <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
    </session>

    <session>
        <ejb-name>GaragisteDao</ejb-name>
        <ejb-class>com.crystaleez.dao.GaragisteDao</ejb-class>
        <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
        <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
    </session>
```

Comment: i did what you told me, unfortunatelly it's not that the reason