Eclipse marks ejb-jar.xml entry <ejb-class> as invalid
I'm on a legacy EJB project using Eclipse with the following ejb-jar.xml:
<ejb-jar version="3.1" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd">
  <display-name>Verwaltung</display-name>
  <enterprise-beans>
    <session>
      <description>EJB für den Zugriff auf die Configuration</description>
      <ejb-name>EnvironmentEntries</ejb-name>
      <init-on-startup>true</init-on-startup>
      <ejb-class>
        some.package.name.EnvironmentEntries
      </ejb-class>
      <session-type>Singleton</session-type>
    </session>
  </enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>

Gives an error:
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'ejb-class'. One of '{
"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":concurrency-management-type,
"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":concurrent-method, 
"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":depends-on,
"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":init-method,
"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":remove-method,
"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":async-method,
"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":transaction-type,
"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":after-begin-method,
"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":before-completion-method,
"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":after-completion-method,
"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":around-invoke,
"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":around-timeout,
"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":env-entry,
"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":ejb-ref,
"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":ejb-local-ref,
"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":service-ref,
"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":resource-ref,
"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":resource-env-ref,
"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":message-destination-ref,
"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":persistence-context-ref,
"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":persistence-unit-ref,
"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":post-construct,
"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":pre-destroy,
"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":data-source,
"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":post-activate,
"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":pre-passivate,
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":security-role-ref,
"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":security-identity}
' is expected.

Screenshot:

I'm not very good at reading XSD files, but according to https://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd and the official TomEE docs https://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/simple-stateless-with-descriptor/ this seems to be fine.
Q:
What's wrong?
Is Eclipse doing some weird validation here (again)? How do you fix or get rid of this?
EDIT:
Suspending all validators in Eclipse doesn't work:


Maybe look in the "XML (Wild Web Developer)" "Validation & Resolution" preferences.

That TomEE doc is for a different schema version than you are using.

I know. Chances are minimal something straightforward as this will matter with a minor version change. I had already tried 3.2 and 3.1, both show the same error.

"straightforward"... I mean it doesn't look like much to me, but I haven't figured it out

The message says that the order of the elements matters. Hover over the session tag name to see the content model, where the parentheses not being followed by a + or * indicates a strict order.
It should be:
<ejb-jar version="3.1" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd">
  <display-name>Verwaltung</display-name>
  <enterprise-beans>
    <session>
      <description>EJB für den Zugriff auf die Configuration</description>
      <ejb-name>EnvironmentEntries</ejb-name>
      <ejb-class>
        some.package.name.EnvironmentEntries
      </ejb-class>
      <session-type>Singleton</session-type>
      <init-on-startup>true</init-on-startup>
    </session>
  </enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>

Servers probably don't care whether the order is correct, but the schema is the schema.

Thanks. Found this one after your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19547203/missing-values-in-ejb-jar-xml
